# How to revert to original CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a  div with a span inside (simplified).

```
<div class="divDash">
    <span>XX</span>
</div>
```

Based on the below CSS, the span is initially hidden and shows only when you hover over the div.

```
.divDash {height:300px;width:300px;border:1px solid gray;}
.divDash span {display:none}
.divDash:hover span {display:inline}
```

Based on some user interaction, I need to hide the span using jQuery...

```
$('.divDash').children('span').hide();
```

And then, based on some other user interaction, I need to restore the original behaviour of the span. If I simply show the span again using `$('.divDash').children('span').show();` then it is shown permanently and not just on hover.

How can I restore the original CSS behaviour so the span shows only on hover?

Comment: try `$('.divDash').children('span').css('display', '');`

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Can't believe I didn't try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert to the default behavior by setting `display: ''`

```
$('.divDash').children('span').css('display', '');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k7ne7yyb/)

Comment: Simply `$('.divDash span').css('display', '');` as well, in addition add or remove class is also good way.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `show` and `hide`, add/remove a specific CSS class that has the behavior you would want.

Comment: Yes, I do believe that is the correct way... I'm currently in a prototyping stage, hence not yet optimized!